# PHP search for string in text file & return result after specific character

Tags: php, string

i want search string in text file. find result and return after : character.

**input is alex**
text file include this item

```
alex:+123
david:+1345
john:+1456
```

output is +123

```
$input = "alex";
file_get_contents("TextFilePath");

//in this step i don't know what should i do
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression match to locate lines beginning with the given input:

```
$input = "alex";
$text = file_get_contents("TextFilePath");
if (preg_match('#^' . preg_quote($input) . ':(.*)#m', $text, $match) {
    // Found input
    var_dump($match[1]);
}
```

Comment: It's an output variable that receives the result from `preg_match` https://php.net/preg_match

Comment: the code only work for alex. when i change input value , output doesnt show.

Comment: Are you using multi-line mode `m` for the regex?

Comment: Then add m to the regex as above

Comment: Thank you very much jspcal. it work.
Can you explain the preg_match code block ? im new in php programming . and i want to know how/where you learn this methods ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best solution, but you can use `file` and loop on the array. `explode` each line to see if the needle was present.

```
function findInAFile($filename, $needle) {
    // read file split on newline
    $lines = file($filename);
    // check each line and return first occurence
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $arr = explode($needle, $line, 2);
        if (isset($arr[1])) {
            return $arr[1];
        }
    }
}

echo findInAFile('file.txt', $input.':');
```